# Why does printing statement returns string result while printing array reference variable of Char datatype in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, println

Currently, I'm learning arrays in JAVA. when I was trying to print reference variable of Primitive and non-primitive data types, I was getting usual results (as I have thought I will get) but when I tried to print the reference variable of 'Char' Datatype, I got characters back as a string result. can someone please explain why does it work like that? and plus if you know why the reference variable of string data type also gives different output as compared to others?

```
int[] arr1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
System.out.println(arr1); // Output : [I@e9e54c2

char[] arr2 = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
System.out.println(arr2); // Output : abcde

String[] arr3 = {"Luke", "Phill","Alex"};
System.out.println(arr3); // Output : [Ljava.lang.String;@6d311334
```

Comment: About the `char[]`, here's why:https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(char%5B%5D)

Comment: This answer from Duncan Jones might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4